# WCF request response lifecycle

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

I am new to WCF and trying to understand a few things.

1. Is every request/response handled in separate mutex threads/process host? Can same thread/process handle multiple requests? Is there any request queuing involved?
2. If I have global/static variables is their scope limited to the given request response sequence?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WCF, there are three methods for instance management of service objects - `PerCall`, `PerSession` and `Single`. This service behavior attribute is known as [`InstanceContextMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

`PerCall` - Creates a new service instance every client method call. Works if your service is stateless.

`PerSession` - Creates a new service instance for each new client proxy. Works if you need to keep state information between calls from the same client.

`Single` - Creates a single service instance which is shared among all clients. Works if you need to share global data throughout your service.

For the threading part of your question, there is a service behavior attribute known as [`ConcurrencyMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.concurrencymode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which handles the details of the threading nature of each service instance. The options are `Single`, `Multiple` and `Reentrant`.

`Single` - The service instances are single-threaded.

`Multiple` - The service instances are multi-threaded. You must handle the synchronization and state consistency of the service object.

`Reentrant` - The service instances are single-threaded, but the service accepts calls when it calls on another service. This requires a bit of overhead in maintaining the state of the service object and handling callbacks on the service.

These two factors combine to control the behavior of your service instances. For example, if you have `InstanceContextMode` and `ConcurrencyMode` set to `Single` and your service receives new messages while the instance is already handling a call, then these messages must wait until your service finishes handling the in progress call before handling the next message (during which time the message may timeout).

Personally, I have never had any real need for anything besides single-threaded, per call service instances. But your requirements may be dramatically different than my own.

There are some pretty good articles linked here on [Instance Management](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86007/ways-to-do-WCF-instance-management-Per-call-Per) and [Concurrency](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/89858/WCF-Concurrency-Single-Multiple-and-Reentrant-and) in WCF.